# Dockerfile : Current path and its contents

Tags: docker, dockerfile, open-telemetry

I added a new `opentelemetry-javaagent.jar` to my home folder, the jar is in the same location as `installPackages.sh` file.

```
FROM local_repo:ubuntu
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=$TZ
RUN pwd && ls -l
COPY ./installPackages.sh /tmp/
COPY ./opentelemetry-javaagent.jar /tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
```

However, when the `ls -l` command is executed I don't see any of these files. The output is:

```
Step 4/18 : RUN pwd && ls -l
 ---> Running in dcc4cae7e26c
/
total 48
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Oct  6 16:47 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 15  2020 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Mar 22 21:15 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar 22 21:14 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 15  2020 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Oct  6 16:47 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Oct  6 16:47 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Oct  6 16:47 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   10 Oct  6 16:47 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:47 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:47 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:47 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 939 root root    0 Mar 22 21:15 proc
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:58 root
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:58 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Oct  6 16:47 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:47 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Mar 22 21:15 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:58 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:47 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Oct  6 16:58 var
Removing intermediate container dcc4cae7e26c
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSwoa.png) Shouldn't I be seeing the files I am copying upon `ls -l`?

[2] The error I get copying opentelemetry jar is

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat opentelemetry-javaagent.jar: file does not exist
```

I have not created a `dockerignore` file explicitly so it must be the default value.

Snapshot of the directory structure, both `installPackages` and the jar is present at the same path. If one is getting copied, the other one should too?
[image]

Comment: You copy the files to /tmp, but you list the files in the root directory. Instead of `ls -l` try `ls -l /tmp`

Comment: I am doing `ls -l` before I copy anything to `tmp`. So I should be able to see whatever I am copying to `tmp` in my current directory no?

Comment: The path is not correct as @Hans Kilian said, but also, you are executing `RUN pwd && ls -l` before copying the jar file. Please, inverse the steps.

Comment: No, `ls -l` is running inside the container not on your host OS, so the files are only visible after you `COPY` them and only in the destination directory, not the source location (which is on your host OS).

Comment: okay, the copying fails too because of the error I indicated. Both the `jar` and the `installPackages` have the same directory structure

Comment: What command are you running to build the image?

Comment: ah, Figured out the mistake. There is another `prep-contents` file which is copying the files to the accurate path. The jar is getting copied now!